# Multiple markers from Backendless database into Mapbox

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi Anyone can help me out this ? My project is required to display multiple markers on mapbox in Backendless UI Builder.
(Rendering locations from backendless database into Mapbox component)
Could you please support how can we get this done ?

Example javascript code is as below

```js
Multiple Markers
__________________________________

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoia29zdGVkIiMWQzbXA3M2ZxYmd5MnkifQ.faOl-gGzibR9yMpZ-i7FTQ';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container : 'map',
        style : 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        zoom : 2
    // starting zoom
    });

    // Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
    map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

    var studioListComplete = [];

    <c:forEach var="studio" items="${studioList}">

    studioListComplete
            .push({
                "type" : "Feature",
                "properties" : {
                    "description" : "<strong>${studio.studioName} (${studio.country})</strong> <br/><br/>" + 
                                    "${studio.studioDescription}<br/><br/>"+
                                    "<strong>City : </strong>${studio.city}<br/>"+
                                    "<strong>Number of employees : </strong>${studio.numberOfEmployees}<br/>"+
                                    "<strong>Phone : </strong>${studio.phoneNumber}<br/><br/>"+

                                    "<a href=\"${studio.webSiteUrl}\" target=\"_blank\">Please visit our website</a>",
                    "icon": "rocket"
                },
                "geometry" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [ "${studio.longitude}",
                            "${studio.latitude}" ]
                }
            });
    //var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    //.setLngLat(["${studio.longitude}", "${studio.latitude}"])
    //.addTo(map);
    </c:forEach>

    console.log(studioListComplete);

    map.on('load', function() {
        // Add a layer showing the places.
        map.addLayer({
            "id" : "places",
            "type" : "symbol",
            "source" : {
                "type" : "geojson",
                "data" : {
                    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
                    "features" : studioListComplete
                }
            },
            "layout" : {
                "icon-image" : "{icon}-15",
                'icon-size': 1,
                "icon-allow-overlap" : true
            }
        });
```

I do not know know to pass output of this api call(https://develop.backendless.com/app/FMS/bl/services/SNService/getSN)
to ${studioList}.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a bit on what the issue you are having is? Right now this question is very broad and it will be difficult for anyone to answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: yes. I have updated code as above